# Abstract Class must override an abstract method?

Tags: c#

Let's say this abstract class:

```cs
abstract public class MyBase {

    abstract public int GetValue();

    <some concrete methods here>
}
```

Now I want to inherit that as another abstract class, implementing `GetValue()` but adding new abstract methods:

```cs
abstract public class MyBase2 : MyBase {

    abstract public int GetValue2();

    public override int GetValue() {
        // some code here
        return something;
    }

}
```

Why do I have to specify `override` for `MyBase2.GetValue()`? Isn't `MyBase.GetValue()` already marked as `abstract` and thus will naturally be overridden by anything inheriting from `MyBase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `MyBase2` class is also marked as `abstract` you should tell the compiler that `GetValue()` is implemented in this class instead of other class(es) higher in hierarchy (implementing `MyBase2`)

Answer (score 4):

> Why do I have to specify override for MyBase2.GetValue()?

This is a paradigm which has been adopted by c++ as well.

The idea is: by explitly having the need to use the keywords `override` for `virtual`  and `abstract`, you will ensure that you're not making a typo when doing the override. Because if you would mot see such a typo, the behaviour, escpecially on `virtual` would change significantly.

Having said that; I still find it strange that the `new` keyword for added methods is still optional and only emits a warning when omitted.